# Jenkins as Crontab, GIT sometimes goes down

Tags: git, jenkins, repository, cron

Currently we have setup Jenkins as a crontab.

I am using git plugin and every minute I pull from different remote repositories in order to run builds.

Problem is that network is bad and sometimes build gets failed since Jenkins can't fetch changes from repository.

What is the best way to dismiss fetching changes if Jenkins can't connect to remote repository?